# pgrouting with an existing road net

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, route

I am tying to use pgrouting in order to calculate the distance that can be passed within a certain time period. Someone has provided me an updated OSM dataset with speeds. From there I am trying to use pgrouting in order to calculate from a certain point on that net to every line segment the distance.

Pgrouting is documented, however there are not that many examples out there. While I think it is an absolute amazing tool. Hence my question here.

------- UPDATE

```
select pgr_createTopology('temp.bikenet_tilburg_4326', 0.000001, 'geom', 'gid');
```

= ok

```
SELECT pgr_analyzegraph('temp.bikenet_tilburg_4326', 0.000001, 'geom', 'gid');
```

= ok

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_drivingDistance('SELECT gid as id, source, target, time as cost FROM schema.table', 1::bigint, 12::bigint, false)
```

The drivingdistance only shows how many line segments i had to pass, which is the costs. But I want it to count the time each segment takes. Think I can built that on top of it but there might be a better option inside.

Comment: the (minimal) function signature is `pgr_disjkstraCost(TEXT, BIGINT, BIGINT)` - try with explicit casts for all columns (e.g. `source::BIGINT AS source`). but then, you likely want to use `pgr_drivingDistance` instead? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572251/how-to-get-a-road-path-which-can-be-travelled-in-10-minutes-from-a-location/51686168) in my answer history that might add some inspiration about how to get back some 'practical' results from this function

Comment: pgr_drivingDistance is definitly what I need; thank you for your comment will update the question soon. So far the forcing column types is not working.

Comment: to your update: the `agg_cost` column in the result set aggregates your `cost` column (if your cost column is just a speed limit, use `(ST_Length/1000) / cost AS cost` to get the time needed to traverse the segment with max. allowed speed; assuming *km* as base unit)

Answer (score 1):

The `pgr_drivingDistance` should return what you need. Just read in the documentation the description of the return values https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_drivingDistance.html#description-of-the-return-values

I don't know, why you write, that "drivingdistance only shows how many line segments i had to pass". The result of the function returns a list of all nodes of your selected network, each with an `agg_cost` attribute, that tells you the cost needed to reach that node from your start point.

If your `cost` column (the cost attribute, that you passed in your SQL query as the first function argument) represents the time to travel along an edge in your network table, then the aggregated costs give you the travel time to that node.